# Python How to distinguish data in python socket module(when server receive.)

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.3

I don't know how to distinguish data which received in server.

I want to distinguish the data by setting MessageID(example name) when I send data or receive data.

Here's the example.:

server

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host=''
port=int(input(Please Enter the port:))
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print('Someone connected.He :%s'%addr)
while True:
    data=conn.recv(1024,MessageID) # I want to make this.
    print(data)
```

client

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host=''
port=int(input(Please Enter the port:))
s.connect((host,port))
data='hello world'
data=data.encode('utf-8') # I encoded data because Python 3.3.3's socket module doesn't
work with string(str) when I send data.
s.send(data,MessageID) # This is what I want.I want to set messageID which can        distinguish data.
```

---

How to make like this?

How other programmers distinguish data in python..?

I really want is : Don't receive if not messageID which server want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to put the `MessageID` into the `data` you're sending. It might be a good idea to use some known protocol for the data, so you know what to expect, but here's a naive example. You will need to implement proper error handling. Note that you will also have to implement a loop to read all of the data, as reading the socket with a single `recv` will eventually lead to a situation where you're receiving partial messages. I don't really know what your data is so I won't make a guess about it.

The client

```
....
message_id = 1
data = '{}:hello world!'.format(message_id)
data = data.encode('utf-8')
s.send(data)
```

The server

```
while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
       # Always handle the case where the client
       # connects but sends no data. This means the socket is closed
       # by the other end.
       break
    message_id, message = data.split(":", 1)
    print "Got message, id: {}, data: {}".format(message_id, message)
```

If you'd implement this using [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) or [json](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) you could simply use dictionaries:

```
# Client
data = {'message_id': 1, 'message': 'hello world'}
data = pickle.dumps(data) # Or json.dumps(data)
s.send(data)

# Server
while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    data = pickle.loads(data) # Or json.loads(data)
    print "Got id: {message_id}, data: {message}".format(**data)
```

Comment: 1. receive -> recv 2. `conn.recv(1024)` may return less than 1024 bytes (partial message). You need a loop to read the whole message. 3. About `if not data`: ["When a recv returns 0 bytes, it means the other side has closed (or is in the process of closing) the connection. You will not receive any more data on this connection. Ever. You may be able to send data successfully"](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/sockets.html)

Comment: I really want is : Don't receive if not messageID which server want.

Comment: @user3312583 your only choice is to discard the data the server sent if the messageid doesn't match. You cannot know what the data is before receiving it.